# TFS 2015 Build,Tests not running in Visual Studio Test build step or vstest.console.exe

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, vstest, tfs-2015

After upgrading both Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio from 2013 update 4 to 2015, i created a build in the new build system. 
The build includes only two steps: One Visual Studio Build step and one Visual Studio Test step. There's only one single simple solution with a class library project and a test project.

The Build step runs fine. The Test step does nothing. It just says

```
Starting test execution, please wait...
```

but the test are not running.

When i edit the VS Test step in the build definition and set the VSTest version to "Visual Studio 2013" instead of "Visual Studio 2015", everything works fine and it outputs as expected:

```
Starting test execution, please wait...
Passed <nameoftest1>
Passed <nameoftest2>
Passed <nameoftest3>
Passed <nameoftest4>
etc
```

I found out that during that build step, the following line gets executed:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe "C:\pathToTestDll\TestProject.dll
```

So i tried to run this from commandline on my own pc, and found out that when i use vstest.console.exe from the Visual Studio 12.0 folder, everything works fine, but when i use vstest.console from the Visual Studio 14.0 folder, the tests are not running.

I also found out that when i run the command prompt as administrator, it runs all the tests with vstest.console from the Visual Studio 14.0 folder.

Has anybody also had this issue, or is there a way to run the whole build (or just the test step) with elevated rights, so i can run my tests with the VSTest Version set to Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: I stumbled upon this situation when our automated VS-Tests weren't found in an XAML build. Running them on the server from console manually using `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe` worked fine however. In our case we had to remove the `appx` from the test source match and concretize it to `tests` instead of `test`.